# difference between isNothing and (== Nothing) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I'm confused about why the two functions below involving `Nothing` are different:

```
coalesce  m1 m2 = if  isNothing m1 then m2 else m1

coalesce' m1 m2 = if  (m1 == Nothing) then m2 else m1
```

The first one has type:

```
λ> :t coalesce
coalesce :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
```

as expected. But the second one has:

```
λ> :t coalesce'
coalesce' :: Eq a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
```

Why does using `(==Nothing)` introduce the `Eq a` constraint?

(GHC 8.2.2)

Comment: It might be worth pointing out explicitly that this difference is a significant one: There are some things (like, in general, functions) that cannot have an `Eq` instance. So `coalesce` would work fine with these, but `coalesce'` would not.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`==` is a function `Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`. You’re making one of its operands `Nothing`, so `a` is a `Maybe b` for some type `b`, but that `Eq a` restriction still applies – the `Maybe b` has to have an `Eq` instance. `Maybe b` includes a definition for such an instance – `Eq (Maybe b)` – for all `Eq b`.

In other words, `==` is just a function and it doesn’t know ahead of time that you’re providing `Nothing` as an argument. It only knows it’s *some* `Maybe a`, and it needs to be able to compare equality if it happens to be a `Just …`.

In other other words, here’s how you can define the `==` that already exists for `Maybe`s:

```
equals a b = case a of
    Nothing -> isNothing b
    Just x -> case b of
        Nothing -> False
        Just y -> x == y
```

Notice how `x == y` appears, meaning there must be an `Eq` instance for the type of `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 6):

Because the type of `==` is

```
(==) :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> Bool
```

Your second definition (`coalesce'`) uses `==`, so it inherits the `Eq` constraint on its arguments from `==`.

---

Strictly speaking `coalesce'` uses `==` on values of type `Maybe a`, but there's an instance

```
instance (Eq a) => Eq (Maybe a) where ...
```

so the `Eq (Maybe a)` constraint becomes `Eq a`, because that's what's needed to support `==` on `Maybe a`.

Answer (score 4):

Let us first aim to design a `(==)` function over `Maybe` values. Usually we consider two things the same if they have the *same* data constructor, and the *parameters* are all equal. So we consider `F x1 x2 x3` and `G y1 y2 y3` the same if `F` and `G` are the same data constructor, and `x1 == y1`, `x2 == y2`, and `x3 == y3`.

So if we implement this for `Maybe`, there are two cases that are equal: two `Nothing`s, and two `Just`s, where the values the `Just`s encapsulate are the same, so:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) where
    (==) Nothing Nothing = True
    (==) (Just x) (Just y) = x == y
    (==) _ _ = False
```

is the most logical way to implement the `Eq` instance for `Maybe a`. In the implementation, we use `x == y`, hence we added the `Eq a` type constraint.

Now Haskell sees functions conceptually as blackboxes. For `Maybe`, it thus sees `(==)` as `(==) :: Eq a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Bool`. If you thus use this `(==)` function, it will always require the type constraint `Eq a`, regardless whether the specific usage will ever need this type constraint to perform the `x == y` check. If you write `(== Nothing)`, then we see, that the second clause (`(==) (Just x) (Just y)`) will never be used, but since Haskell treats functions as blackboxes, it does not known in what cases the type constraint is relevant.

[**`isNothing :: Maybe a -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:isNothing) only checks if the value is a `Nothing`, if it is a `Just`, then it is always `False`, regardless what the value is the `Just` constructor wraps, it is thus implemented like:

```
isNothing :: Maybe a -> Bool
isNothing Nothing = True
isNothing _ = False
```

So we do not need the `Eq a` type constraint here: we do not check equality of elements `Just` constructor(s) wrap. So again if we use this, Haskell only checks the type signature, notices that there is no `Eq a` type constraint involved and hence does not add it to functions that use this function.

Notice that what you implement here actually already is implemented in the `Control.Applicative` module: [**`(<|>) :: Alternative f => f a -> f a -> f a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-), for example:

```
Prelude> import Control.Applicative
Prelude Control.Applicative> (<|>) Nothing Nothing
Nothing
Prelude Control.Applicative> (<|>) Nothing (Just 3)
Just 3
Prelude Control.Applicative> (<|>) (Just 3) Nothing
Just 3
Prelude Control.Applicative> (<|>) (Just 3) (Just 2)
Just 3
```